# Macbook Pro 2016 - Cursor doesn't move when making selections/moving objects

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mouse, trackpad, cursor

I have a MacBook Pro 15" 2016 with Touch Bar on OS Catalina 10.15.7. For the last few months I've been having the issue; when I move an object in an application like Adobe Illustrator, Adobe InDesign, Figma, or Photoshop, I can move the object but the cursor will not move with it. I thought it was an issue with my Touch Pad, but with an external mouse, I have the same issue.

[image: Cursor Problem Animated GIF]

With InDesign, it's not that big of an issue since I can see the bounding boxes of the object moving around, but dragging objects around in Figma does have issues where I can't see where an object is going.

Does anyone else have this issue and knows a fix? Because it's really annoying.

Comment: What version of CC are you using? In Adobe apps, switch off the hardware acceleration & see what happens.